# Spring Transactional on method with multiple db operation

Tags: spring, transactions

I'm little confused. I though `@Transactional` on method means all operations or none.

Say I have this method:

```
@Transactional
public void fewDbOpeations(){
    calculation1();
    myDao.saveResult();
    calculation2();
    myDao.saveResult();
}
```

Say `calculation2()` throw exception or my second call to `myDao.saveResult` goes wrong , what I see is the even though the whole method annotated with `@Transactional` the saving result after `calculation1()` call is successful.

That is my first interaction with database saved the records I want but the second one failed but I thought because the method is `@Transactinal` even the first call to save to database should be rolled back.

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you handle exceptions and if there are still `@Transactional` annotated on those internal method calls.

To have "all or nothing" behaviour in `fewDbOpeations()`, make sure the followings for all the internal method calls :

- Do not annotated with `@Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW)`
- Do not catch the exception inside and not throw out. Throw `RuntimeException` or `Error` but not checked `Exception` (Assume you are using default setting).

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Transactional (rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void fewDbOpeations(){
    calculation1();
    myDao.saveResult();
    calculation2();
    myDao.saveResult();
}
```

Try using this as well and throw Exceptions.